# How to add japanese zip code symbol 〒 in xelatex?

Tags: xetex, unicode

I would like to write the japanese zip code symbol 〒 (unicode U+3012) in xelatex. However, when I put it in my source, it simply gets omitted in the final document, without raising any error. I guess I need to add a font containing that symbol, but do not know how to and which font to add. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**: As David Carlisle correctly pointed out, there is a message about a missing character, hidden deep inside the output.log. But nothing which would make xelatex crash like a missing package.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/575584/2388 for a way to identify fonts with a symbol.

Comment: there will be a warning `missing character` in the log file

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed, there is. On line 231 of 248 in my output.log. Sorry I missed that.

Comment: from next year you will be able to set `\tracinglostchars` to 3 to make it an error not a warning, _everybody_ misses the current quite warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find a font on your system that has the glyph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

% use a font that has U+3012; ipag.ttf is in TeX Live
\newfontface{\postalmarkfont}{ipag.ttf}

\newunicodechar{〒}{{\normalfont\postalmarkfont 〒}}

\begin{document}

This is the postal mark 〒

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a “more generic” way, where you state the path where the font is located at. Use the actual path for your system.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

% use a font that has U+3012; ipag.ttf is in TeX Live
\newfontface{\postalmarkfont}{ipag}[
  Extension=.ttf,
  Path=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/ipaex/,
  Scale=MatchUppercase,
]

\newunicodechar{〒}{{\normalfont\postalmarkfont 〒}}

\begin{document}

This is the postal mark 〒

\end{document}
```

I also added the Scale option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's quick! Now I just need to find out how to make xelatex find the font which is installed on my system in `/usr/share/fonts/ipa-gothic/ipag.ttf`

Comment: @laolux Doesn't the code I provided find it?

Comment: No, I tried your code and get `! Package fontspec Error: The font "ipag" cannot be found.`

Comment: Try with `\newfontface{\postalmarkfont}{ipag}[Extension=.ttf,Path=/usr/share/fonts/ipa-gothic/]`

Comment: Great, the new version works when I change the path to suit my system.